# How to hide an element in TinyMCE popup window?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm trying to build a custom plugin based on a stock TinyMCE 4 image plugin. It'll have two drop-downs. When user clicks the first one - I'd like to hide the second one (css style `display: none;`).

Here is a bit of code that adds drop-downs in the initializer:

```
        targetTest1ListCtrl = {
            name: 'test1',
            type: 'listbox',
            label: 'Test1',
            values: buildValues('target_list', 'target', InputDataArray),
            onClick: function(e) {
                    //code I'm looking for
            },
        };
generalFormItems.push(targetTest1ListCtrl);
        targetTest2ListCtrl = {
            name: 'test2',
            type: 'listbox',
            label: 'Test2',
            values: buildValues('target_list', 'target', InputDataArray2)
        };
generalFormItems.push(targetTest2ListCtrl);
```

Both drop-downs generate just fine, if I put `alert` in my onclick event - it's triggered perfectly fine, but in no way I can find how to access my `test2` through the TinyMCE and change styling on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer:

```
sampleElement = win.find('#test2')[0];
sampleElement.hide();
```

Where `#test2` is `#`+name of your Ctrl.

Answer (score 0):

editor.editorManager.dom.DomQuery("button[title='you_button_title']")[0].style.display = 'none';

Comment: Please explain your code-only solution. How does it work? Why does that solve the problem?